# Need message size for each child record

Tags: c#, linq

I have a below `LINQ` query where I want to select fill `child` data from `Master` data and additionally I want to calculate size too.

```
this.Size = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Child).Length;
```

Here is query and master data,

```
var mast = new List<Master>
{
    new Master{Id=1, Name="Name1"},
    new Master{Id=2, Name="Name1"},
    new Master{Id=3, Name="Name11"},
    new Master{Id=4, Name="Name11"},
};

var g = from data in mast
        group data by new { data.Name } into T
        select new Message(T.Select(t => new Child
        {
            Name = t.Name
        }).ToList());
```

and supporting classes,

```
public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Child Child { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public Message(Child Child)
    {
        this.Child = Child;
        this.Size = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Child).Length;
    }
}
```

Currently getting error with below as cast issue between List and single item,

```
select new Message(T.Select(t => new Child
                    {
                        Name = t.Name
                    }).ToList());
```

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'TestApp.Child'  TestApp

What needs to be done here? Thanks!

**EDIT**: The final result I am trying to achieve is a `List<List<Message>>`, where the inner `List<Message>` is grouped by name; so, based on my example data, there would be 2 lists of `Message`s, containing 2 items each:

- List 1:

  - Message: Name: Name1, Size 16
  - Message: Name: Name1, Size 16
- List 2:

  - Message: Name: Name11, Size 17
  - Message: Name: Name11, Size 17

Comment: Show us the error output at least.

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'TestApp.Child' TestApp

Comment: You're passing a `List<Child>` to `Message` constructor... Your `ToList` call does not make sense there

Comment: Ok two things 1. Constructor expecting single element and you are passing list. 2. If you are sure that it will always be 1 child then you FirstOrDefault() instead of select just to be safe.

Comment: No, I can pass all elements, but then how to calculate each element size?

Comment: I think you want `First()` or `Single()` instead of `ToList()`

Comment: No I need `ToList()` only but also want size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a call to `FirstOrDefault`, which passes a `IEnumerable<Child>` returned from the `T.Select` call to `Message` constructor.

Your `ToList` call is also in the wrong spot - you're just converting that `IEnumerable<Child>` to `List<Child>`, when you actually want a `List<Message>`, after each `Message` has been created.

Change to:

```
var g = (from data in mast
        group data by new { data.Name } into T
        select new Message(T.Select(t => new Child
        {
            Name = t.Name
        }).FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
```

*EDIT*: I think you're concerned about the `FirstOrDefault` call only returning 1 value - however, keep in mind, it's 1 `Child` *per Name*, since you just grouped them by name - exactly what you want. The final `List<Message>` contains unique names with sizes, as desired.

**EDIT 2.0**: Ok, based on your own answer, which clarified your question, I think this query will work better for your needs:

```
var messages = mast.GroupBy(m => m.Name)
                    .Select(nameGroup => Enumerable.Repeat(
                        new Message(new Child() { Name = nameGroup.Key }), nameGroup.Count()).ToList()
                    ).ToList();
```

The above will produce a `List<List<Message>>`, grouped by name (but keeping the original message count), and each message will have the `Size` property calculated.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` always give me only 1 record

Comment: Yes, but from grouping by name you can only have 1 record at that time! I just ran this solution (my parens were off, answered from my phone initially, bad idea, lol) - I get a list of 2 Messages back; first "Name1", Size 16, and second "Name11", Size 17.

Comment: Thanks, but I want all 4 record back and 2 in each group, but also want to calculate the size

Comment: `Message` constructor helping me to calculate the size, please check my answer and let me know for any improvement. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot.cccccccccccccccc